# Descending list of polygons based on how many points they contain

Tags: attribute-joins

I have a polygon and a point table and want to put the polygons in descending order based on how many points they contain, in other words find the polygons containing most points

I tried experimenting with count and st_contains but I don't think I'm getting the desired results

Could anyone shed some light please by writing an example query?

I am using PostgreSQL and PgAdmin and new to them.

Comment: What software do you use?

Comment: Are you using PostGIS?

Answer (score 2):

For PostgreSQL/PostGIS, you should use [ST_NPoints](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_NPoints.html) :

```
Select * from mytable order by st_npoints(geom) desc
```

where geom is your geometry column